# How to enable secure boot for AsRock z370 pro4 to upgrade to Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10, bios

How to enable secure boot for AsRock z370 pro4 to upgrade to Windows 11?

I just can’t get this done. This is an Intel board, Asrock z70 pro4 with Intel i5-8400

Error in PC health check is:

> "This PC must support secure boot"

I can get in the bios no problem, but I need detailed steps to do this.

Comment: did you look at the manual for the motherboard?

Comment: Nope, thought the board is too old! I'll do that right now

Comment: Looked at manual, secure boot is indeed enabled, but not working

Comment: @BrunoVincent - What do you mean it’s enabled but “not working”? If it’s enabled, it has to be working, if Windows boots.

Comment: Your CPU is also not supported by Windows 11. So, the error message is probably about something else.

Comment: And it fails on other requirements as well. Also if your current OS is installed in Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode you can't upgrade no matter what because Windows 11 won't support such mode.

Comment: It passes all other requirements, what I mean by not working is this error from Windows:  "This PC must support secure boot", I went into the BIOS, and it is indeed set to secure boot, but the error comes back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure Boot is implemented for UEFI boot only: if your system boots using the legacy BIOS style, Secure Boot cannot be used.

On Windows, the choice of boot method is coupled to the choice of partitioning style on the system disk: UEFI-bootable systems must use a GPT-partitioned system disk, and BIOS-bootable systems must use classic MBR partitioning on the system disk.

So if your current system disk is partitioned MBR-style, then you are booting in legacy BIOS style and your BIOS's legacy/UEFI selection must have higher priority than the "Secure Boot enable/disable" selection.

If you are booting from a Windows 11 installation media to do the upgrade, be careful to boot the media in UEFI mode. Since your motherboard supports both UEFI and legacy BIOS boot, it might offer you two ways to boot any external media. For simplicity, if your current OS boots in UEFI mode, you might want to change any boot method selection settings in the BIOS to "CSM disabled"/"UEFI only" to ensure no legacy BIOS-style boot from removable media will be offered, to minimize the chance of any mistakes.

Also, note that if you have an old GPU that does not include native UEFI support, then the system must enable CSM (= legacy BIOS compatibility support) to activate the GPU at boot. If you are using the Intel iGPU integrated to the processor, this is not a problem for you. But if you are using an old GPU card, you might want to download and run [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and verify that the UEFI support checkbox under the GPU chip manufacturer's logo is checked. If not, see if the GPU vendor offers a video BIOS update for the card that would add native UEFI support.

Comment: That's an insanely good reply, I will try to convert my C drive to GPT and see if that works, otherwise I have to re-install windows and avoid legacy boot, right?

Comment: To successfully convert your current Windows installation from BIOS to UEFI boot, just converting the partitioning is not enough. You will also have to create a small (100 MB should suffice) EFI System Partition and install a UEFI Windows bootloader to it. Apparently this is achievable, but if you are uncertain of your skill level, a complete reinstallation of Windows in UEFI mode might be easier.

Answer (score -1):

To confirm what @ChanganAuto said previously do following:
Click the ‘Windows’ search key on your computer and launch (type in) ‘System Information’.
If you see such output as you can see on mine :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWemx.png)

You have to install new windows.

Comment: "You have to install new windows." - This is absolutely a false statement. There is a solution that DOES NOT involve reinstalling Windows.

Comment: To further explain the reason this answer is incorrect, the author could not even enable Secure Boot, and have a Legacy boot installation of Windows.  Secure Boot is incompatible with Legacy Boot, you cannot even enable Secure Boot, if Windows is installed in Legacy Mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).